# Why is name not defined?

Tags: python

I am trying to write inside of a excel file trying to make a new row with data but it just says name is not defined.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("H:\Grade10\Cs\Mir Hussain 12.04.00.xlsx")

sheet = wb.active

def New():
    choice = input("Would you like to add a new row?")
    if choice == 'Yes':
        Name = input("What is the name of that celebirty")
        Age = input("What is the age of the celebirty")
        Height = input('What is the height of the celebirty')
        DOB = input('What is the Date of birth of the celebirty')
    elif choice == 'No':
        exit
New()
data = [(Name,Age,Height,DOB)]

for row in data:
    sheet.append(row)

wb.save('H:\Grade10\Cs\Mir Hussain 12.04.00.xlsx')
```

Comment: Because `Name` is a local variable in `New`

Comment: `Name` is local to `New`, not global, so it's not defined after `New` returns and `data` tries to use it.

Comment: Even it you make it global, `exit` by itself won't exit your script, so `Name` won't be defined after `New` returns when `choice != "Yes"`. You have to *call* `exit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `Name` is defined as a local variable; it's not defined after `New` returns.
2. `exit` by itself does not exit your script, so even if `choice != "Yes"`, `New` still returns and your script continues.

While you could declare `New` to be global, it would be far better to *return* the input values from the function.

```
def New():
    choice = input("Would you like to add a new row?")
    if choice != 'Yes':
        exit()

    Name = input("What is the name of that celebirty")
    Age = input("What is the age of the celebirty")
    Height = input('What is the height of the celebirty')
    DOB = input('What is the Date of birth of the celebirty')
    return Name, Age, Height, DOB

name, age, height, dob = New()
data = [(name, age, height, dob)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Name` (and the other variables) are defined in the `New` function and thus are local to that scope.  That means that those names are not defined outside of the function.  What you should do is return those values to the caller:

```py
def New():
    ...
    Name = ...
    Age = ...
    Height = ...
    DOB = ...
    return Name, Age, Height, DOB

Name, Age, Height, DOB = New()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you haven't created the variables Name, Age, Height, and DOB before using them in your data variable. You need to create these variables and set them to the inputted values before using them in the data variable.